How to handle varying Feature Dimensions in Graph Neural Networks training?
I have a question about how to handle datasets with different feature dimensions when training Graph Neural Networks (GNNs). For example, in one dataset (Dataset A), the node features have a dimension of 4 and the edge features have a dimension of 16. In another dataset (Dataset B), the node features are 5-dimensional, and the edge features are 25-dimensional. Other datasets I might use also have different feature sizes.
How do you typically handle this kind of variation in feature dimensions when training a GNN?
